# JQuery ajax/post - setting JSON in the data field causes JsonMappingException

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am having issues sending a JQuery post to my server.  I have narrowed the problem down to the data field not being set correctly in my javascript, which leads to an exception:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize
>   instance of com.myserver.rest.messages.dto.NewMessageDTO
>   out of START_ARRAY token

The code that **works**, but not very clean:

```
     $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "../resources/messages/",
               data: '{"subject": "' + subject +
                     '", "message": "' + message +
                     '", "messageType": "' + type +
                     '", "employeeIDs": [' + employeeIDs +
                     '], "assignmentIDs": [' + assignmentIDs +']}',
               contentType: "application/json",
               success: successHandler,
               error: defaultErrorHandler
            });
```

Which renders to:

> {"subject": "test", "message": "test", "messageType": "MESSAGE", "employeeIDs": [461,485], "assignmentIDs": [103]}

The code that **does not work**, but is cleaner:

```
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "../resources/messages/",
               data: {'subject': subject, 'message': message, 'messageType': type, 'employeeIDs[]': employeeIDs, 'assignmentIDs[]': assignmentIDs},
               contentType: "application/json",
               success: successHandler,
               error: defaultErrorHandler
            });
```

Which is rendering as application/x-www-form-urlencoded for some reason:

> subject=test&message=test&messageType=MESSAGE&employeeIDs%5B%5D=461&employeeIDs%5B%5D=485&assignmentIDs%5B%5D=103

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`contentType: "application/json"` means you are expecting JSON as a result of the call. All data is [converted to a query string](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) prior to sending.

The less-clean code is sending the data as a JSON string, which is apparently what `../resources/messages/` expects.

To make that more clean and keep the data as a JSON string:

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '../resources/messages/',
    'data': '{' +
        "'subject':" + subject + ','
        "'message':" message + ','
        "'messageType':" type + ','
        "'employeeIDs':[" employeeIDs + '],'
        "'assignmentIDs':[" assignmentIDs + ']' +
    '}',
    'contentType': "application/json",
    'success': successHandler,
    'error': defaultErrorHandler
});
```

or

```
var data = {
    'subject': subject,
    'message': message,
    'messageType': type,
    'employeeIDs': employeeIDs[]
    'assignmentIDs': assignmentIDs[]
};
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '../resources/messages/',
    'data': JSON.stringify(data), //assuming you have the JSON library linked.
    'contentType': "application/json",
    'success': successHandler,
    'error': defaultErrorHandler
});
```

Hope this helps,

Pete

Comment: was just about to answer with nearly the exact same solution. This is much cleaner.

Comment: Pete - Using JSON.stringify worked!  This is a much cleaner approach than building up the JSON string myself.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I did have to remove the [] on the employeeIDs and assignmentIDs in the data var.  IntelliJ was giving me an 'expression expected' error.

Comment: Be aware that `JSON.stringify` is not available in all browsers. I believe IE8 supports this but not earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work fine and much cleaner.

```
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../resources/messages/",
           data: {
                subject: subject, 
                message: message, 
                messageType: type, 
                employeeIDs: employeeIDs, 
                assignmentIDs: assignmentIDs
           },
           contentType: "application/json",
           success: successHandler,
           error: defaultErrorHandler
        });
```

The issue in your first part of the code is, your are sending the whole data as one string where it should be a key/value pair for each data attribute. In the second part you are not creating the key names properly for array fields. You don't have to include `[]` for array fields.

Comment: Nope, this did not work.  employeeIDs and assignmentIDs are both arrays, so not sure how to handle the conversion to json

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, but your answer did not work and I do not want the others that read this to be lead in the wrong direction

Comment: That is because you did not specify the complete information in the question. How will I know `employeeIDs` is not an array and contains comma separated employee ids? Same applies to assigmentIDs. If I knew that, my answer would have taken care of that.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are a bit wacky, try this:

```
{'subject': subject, 'message': message, 'messageType': type, 'employeeIDs': employeeIDs, 'assignmentIDs': assignmentIDs}
```

This assumes that `employeeIDs` and `assignmentIDs` are arrays.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jb6MA/

Comment: I tried this too with no luck.  It is still converting the json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: You can then decode it in your server-side code into an object. I use PHP, and in PHP there is a `json_decode()` function that takes a string and returns an object.

Comment: An explanation for the down-vote would be much appreciated. The reason for the down-vote is most likely something I want to know about. Thanks.

Comment: @TravisNelson `json_decode` probably isn't what you want. I was thinking about it and you just need to de-serialize the variables in your server-side script.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, but your answer did not work and I do not want the others that read this to be lead in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

In your working example you have variables called `employeeIDs` and `assignmentIDs` but in your non-working code, you have appended `[]` to the end of each.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON schema, strings are only valid if they are enclosed with double-quotes: http://www.json.org/. A lot of implementations are not strict about this, but it looks like your server's implementation is.